# How to aggregate multiple calues in this postgresql query?

Tags: postgresql

This is my query:

```sql
SELECT "vehicle"."id",
       "vehicle"."description",
       "tag"."id" AS "tag_id", 
       "tag"."name" AS "tag_name"
FROM "vehicle" 
INNER JOIN "vehicle_tag_pivot" ON "vehicle"."id" = "vehicle_tag_pivot"."vehicle_id" 
INNER JOIN "tag" ON "vehicle_tag_pivot"."tag_id" = "tag"."id" 

WHERE "tag"."name" IN ('car', 'busses')
AND "vehicle"."category_id" = '1E4FD2C5-C32E-4E3F-91B3-45478BCF0185'
```

I only have one vehicle in my database. It has two tags -> `car` and `busses` (this is test data).
So when I run the query, it returns The exact same vehicle showing the 2 tags it has.

[image]

How do I get it to return the vehicle once? I do not really want to return the tag_name. I only want to filter and return all the vehicles that has the both tags `car` and `busses`.  If one vehicle has both those tags, then it should return that vehicle only. But instead it is returning the same vehicle twice showing its tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```sql
SELECT i.*
FROM "interest" as "i"
where i.id in (
    select it.interest_id
    from interest_tag_pivot it
    join tag t on it.tag_id = t.id
    where t.name in ('car', 'busses')
    group by it.interest_id
    having count (*) = 2
)
and i.category_id = '1E4FD2C5-C32E-4E3F-91B3-45478BCF0185'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not `JOIN` - joins leads to duplications. Put all tags logic to `WHERE EXISTS(...)` or similar.

Here two scalar subqueries comparison in `WHERE`, try this (important! - it is assumed that tags for each vehicle can't duplicate, so we can compare its counts):

```sql
WITH required_tags(val) AS (
  VALUES ('car'),
         ('busses')
)
SELECT "vehicle"."id",
       "vehicle"."description",
       "tag"."id" AS "tag_id", 
       "tag"."name" AS "tag_name"
FROM "vehicle" 
WHERE "vehicle"."category_id" = '1E4FD2C5-C32E-4E3F-91B3-45478BCF0185'
  AND (
    -- count matching tags...
    SELECT count(1)
    FROM "vehicle_tag_pivot"
      INNER JOIN "tag" ON "vehicle_tag_pivot"."tag_id" = "tag"."id"
    WHERE "vehicle"."id" = "vehicle_tag_pivot"."vehicle_id"
      AND "tag"."name" IN (SELECT val FROM required_tags)
    ) = (
      -- ...equals to count required tags
      SELECT count(1) 
      FROM required_tags 
    )
```